# Html helper to render UI elements from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am populating a table with education records from a section of an html page. I am using hidden inputs so as to be able to submit the data from my viewmodel. Because I cannot find a way to use Html helpers (such as Html.HiddenFor) from javascript codes, I had to prepopulate the table so as to copy the appropriate markup for the javascript to render, for example

```
'<td>' + degreeaward + '<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Degree Awarded field is required." id="Educations_' + eduTableRowCount + '__DegreeAwarded" name="Educations[' + eduTableRowCount + '].DegreeAwarded" type="hidden" value=' + degreeaward + '>' + '</td>' +
```

The first problem is that the code becomes messy. The second is that because I am manually generating the list index number (eduTableRowCount) for the input id, if I delete one of the rows from the table, the numbering becomes distorted and I wont have all rows submitted.
My view model class is:

```
public class EduAndProfessionalBackground
{
    public long ProfileId { get; set; }

    public List<WorkExperience> WorkExperiences { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="You must add at least one education info")]
    public List<Education> Educations { get; set; }
}
public class Education
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Institution Name")]
    public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Concentration { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Degree Awarded")]
    public string DegreeAwarded { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public bool StillStudiesHere { get; set; } = false;
}
```

The code I use to prepopulate the table when the page first loads (according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220036)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Educations.Count; i++)
                                                {
                                                    <tr style="font-size:12px">
                                                      ...
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Educations[i].Concentration)
                                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Educations[i].Concentration)
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Educations[i].DegreeAwarded)
                                                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Educations[i].DegreeAwarded)
                                                        </td>
                                                        ...
                                                        <td style="width:100px;text-align:center; padding:5px">
                                                            <button class="delete btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" id="btnDeleteEdu">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                                                            </button>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                }
```

The javascript code for adding more rows to the table:

```
var concentration = $("#Concentration").val();
var degreeaward = $("#DegreeAwarded").val();
 var eduTableRowCount = document.getElementById("table_edu").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
eduTableRowCount = eduTableRowCount - 1; // if the number of rows in the table is 4, the next item should have an index of 3
if ((instiName && concentration && degreeaward && start) && (end || stillStudiesHere)) {
    var newEduItem = '<tr style="font-size:12px">' +

           '<td>' + concentration + '<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Concentration field is required." id="Educations_' + eduTableRowCount + '__Concentration" name="Educations[' + eduTableRowCount + '].Concentration" type="hidden" value=' + concenatration + '>' + '</td>' +
           '<td>' + degreeaward + '<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Degree Awarded field is required." id="Educations_' + eduTableRowCount + '__DegreeAwarded" name="Educations[' + eduTableRowCount + '].DegreeAwarded" type="hidden" value=' + degreeaward + '>' + '</td>' +

        $('#table_edu').append(education);
}
```

The information I got from the following links: [accessing viewmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665597/accessing-viewmodel-in-js-file-asp-net-mvc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361364/accessing-mvcs-model-property-from-javascript), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391402/access-model-in-javascript-asp-net-mvc-razor/21391556) and [JS and Html helpers](https://forums.asp.net/t/1789737.aspx?JavaScript%20files%20and%20HTML%20Helpers) are only on how to access data from viewmodels and have not helped in solving my problem.
I would appreciate a better approach to achieve my aim and I would be glad to add more details if anything is unclear.

Comment: You cannot use use `HtmlHelper` methods in javascript. Javascript runs on the client and c# code runs on the server. Refer [Submit same Partial View called multiple times data to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options,

Comment: and [A Partial View passing a collection using the Html.BeginCollectionItem helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a detailed example using `BeginColletionItem`

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed the example from the second link and it solved my problem. However, I ran into a problem which I fixed long after I realized the essence of the string argument in the BeginCollectionItem method.